# Is it possible to send sms with an unplugged sim?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, sim-card

Suppose I have a SIM (which can be used to send SMS when plugged onto a phone of course), how can I send SMS using this SIM number when the SIM is not plugged to any device(i.e., just put it away)? Note: I don't mind what platform the sms is sent from (e.g., it can be sent from a PC, a smart phone), so any possible solutions? I don't mind solutions which involves coding or programming (e.g., by calling APIs) as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Note highly simplified/high level answer:

In order to send an SMS, USSD, Call or Data etc the Mobile Network will need to provide the device with a special "key" that is used in the communications. I.e. to send and SMS you will need an encryption key to tell the network to send an SMS.

The issue is that this key is dynamic, it changes based on network configuration. The only way to get a key is to use your SIM as it contains a component of the key.

SIM cards (and Bank chip cards) are really a marvel as they are a very good example of superb security, they have been around in Billions of units for more than 30 years, but have and continue to thwart hacking attempts for the most part.

To answer your question, You need the SIM card to get access to production mobile networks.

Answer (score 0):

If by saying **"SIM is not plugged to a phone"** you still Ok about SIM to be plugged into some other device - you defintely can use USB/GSM-modems and standalone GSM-gateways.

Also you may want to consider hardware solutions such as GSM-gateways+SIM-banks. SIM-card is placed in the special non-GSM box (SIM-bank) and available for remote commutation into GSM-box (gsm-gateway) via Internet/Ethernet. Commonly SIM-bank holds hundreds of sim-cards remotely available, and GSM-gateways have only few dozens of real gsm-channels (due to hardware cost saving). Everything is controllable via manufacturer-specific API and/or GUI.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. What I want is sending sms when the SIM is not plugged to any device. I  have modified my question to make it clear.